# Split excel one column in to two

Tags: excel, csv

please see my excel format

```
No  Category

1    Electronics>Mobiles

2    Fashion>Watches
```

How can i split this category column in to two in excel so that one column Electronics or fashion and in other column Mobiles/ watches

example

```
1 Electronics Mobiles
2 Fashion     Watches
```

Please help 
I tried the following formula , but not working .
    =LEFT(B2,FIND(">",B2)-1)

Comment: Use text to columns, with `>` as the delimiter

Comment: Please give the formula . I don't know so much about excel

Comment: Then what a perfect opportunity to learn a new skill in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use text to columns, with the "Delimited" option to split the data out for you:

[image]

Comment: Really thank you for the solution . It's working . I have one more doubt , in some column it is electronis|bb  how to remove all |bb in columns ,like find and replace

Comment: Press `Ctrl + H` and use the replace dialog would be the quickest way. Don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your problem (click the tick on the left)

Comment: I have other doubt . When i Apply a formula to cell , then i get answer . But i double click on that cell it s showing formula . I don't want to show formula to others . How to hide this

Comment: Please start a new question as this is a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in cell `C2`:

`=LEFT(B2,FIND(">",B2,1)-1)`

Then the other part of the string in `D2`:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(">",A1,1))`

#### result:

```
-----+------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
  x  |      A     |         B           |       C      |     D    |
-----+------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
  1  |     No     |      Category       |              |          |
-----+------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
  2  |      1     | Electronics>Mobiles |  Electronics |  Mobiles |
-----+------------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

for excel 2010 choose data leaf in top menu then (with column selected) "text to columns" button and choose delimeter other -> >
That's it - enjoy